# jQuery keypress CTRL+S event does not work on Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, keypress

How come the `keypress` event below does not work on Chrome and Safari? It works well in Firefox!

Something have I missed for Chrome & Safari?

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {                                       

    if ((event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) || (event.which == 19)) {

        // Trigger click.
        $("form input[type=submit][name=update]",object_popup).click();
            alert("Keys down are Ctrl + s + Return");

    } else if ((event.which == 120 && event.ctrlKey) || (event.which == 19)){

        // Trigger click.
        $(".ps-button-close",object_popup).click();
        alert("Keys down are Ctrl + x + Return");

    } else {
        return true;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Chrome/ Safari will fall back to the default and save the webpage instead when I use ctl+s and an alert sound when I use ctl+x.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Letz/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must slightly change your code to:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {

  var currKey=0,e=e||event; 
  currKey=e.keyCode||e.which||e.charCode;

    if (!( String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase() == 's' && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19))  {
       return true; 
    }    

    event.preventDefault();       
    alert("Keys down are Ctrl + s + Return");     
    return false;

});
```

[Online Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GuWVf/)

Comment: thanks. I have tried it but no change at all on chrome and safari... :(

Comment: Did you try changing it to `$(document)` instead of `$(window)`?

Comment: yes I tried it. still the same. and now the firefox is not working... test 1- http://jsfiddle.net/2Letz/3/ test 2- http://jsfiddle.net/2Letz/4/

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer and example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Letz/15/

Comment: Glad to help, my friend! ;)

Comment: one more thing - how can I add ctr+x in that condition?

Comment: Hmm. I must play with this again.. Hold on, please!

Comment: The best I could offer is to put it in to two different keypresses: http://jsfiddle.net/GuWVf/